Why do manufacturers recommend 27.5" MTBs for people over 5'7"
I am 175cm (5'8") and I see on bike manufacturers' websites that 27.5" are recommended for my height. What makes 26" MTBs unsuitable for people at my height?

Can you indicate what manufacturers propose that? I may have a western european bias, but it seems to me that 26" is totally out of fashion now, the default is 29" and 27.5" is proposed by some manufacturers for the smaller sizes (but not all of them). I checked the Rockriders on Decathlon Türkiye, and the only 26" they sell is a kid MTB. Rider under 175cm may be proposed a 27.5", but taller riders will for sure have 29".

I see that on Merida and Giant's websites.

OK, there's then probably a shortcut: they don't recommend 27.5" for people over 175cm, they offer certain models in 27.5" only, and others in 29", but the differentiation is based on the price point and/or riding preferences, not height. If they do, it will be 27.5" for smaller riders, but not taller ones.

26" is indeed totally out of fashion these days. People normally use 29 but really small people (likely not you) may want 27.5" instead. It is also a matter of riding style. 27.5" rolls harder over uneven surface, but may be more agile when turning and accelerating. And lighter. But 29" is the norm.
Nothing makes 26" unsuitable for people of any height. Even very tall people may ride them if the frame and fork is large enough. But new models are not really made in such sizes or quite rarely (e.g., Merida Matts used to be 26" even relatively recently but is now 27.5" - for riders of all heights).
26" mountain bikes do not roll well enough over roots, rocks and other uneven surface.
I am 174 cm tall and have an old 26" and a newer (but made only 2 years later) 29" inch one. Both can be used but they ride differently.
